# jQuery Validate Regex Case Insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I understand (?i) would make my regex case insensitive, but I am unsure on where to place it. I've already wasted sometime trying to figure this out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am using the jQuery Validate plugin for emails, right now if I use a capital it flags it as invalid.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myEmail", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional( element ) || ( /^[a-z0-9]+([-._][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$/.test( value ) && /^(?=.{1,64}@.{4,64}$)(?=.{6,100}$).*/.test( value ) );
}, 'Please enter valid email address.');
```

Comment: use `/^[a-z0-9]+([-._][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$/i`..there is no inline case sensitive flag in JS

Comment: Thank you rock, I am upset it only took one little letter haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add modifier `i` and in [JavaScript regex modifiers are at the end after `/`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags).

```
/^[a-z0-9]+([-._][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$/i
```